# Problema para capturar texto dentro de un Iframe

Tags: javascript, extensión-google-chrome

Tengo pocos meses aprendiendo Javascript y tengo el siguiente problema.

Suelo trabajar en una página de microtrabajos, en esa página colocan un listado de trabajos que van actualizando y uno debe ir chequeando para ver los nuevos trabajos que le interesan. Para eso usaba una extensión de Chrome que actualizaba la página cada cierto tiempo y luego buscaba las palabras claves que le indicaba y me daba una alerta cuando la encontraba. Recientemente la página cambió y la lista de trabajos ahora se renderiza con React en la página dentro de in iframe, desde entonces la parte de la extensión encargada de buscar las palabras claves dejó de funcionar.

Entonces me decidí a crear yo mismo una extensión que haga eso, pero me encuentro que no me es posible acceder al texto que está dentro del iframe.
Probé con `getElementById`, `querySelector`, `innerText`, `textContent`, `Window.find()` pero únicamente logré capturar el texto que está fuera del iframe.

Con este código logro meter el Node del iframe en una variable pero no puedo sacar nada dentro:

```
const ifr = document.querySelector("iframe")
```

Investigando encontré varias soluciones utilizando `contentWindow.document` pero al usarlo tengo el error de CORS (cross-origin):

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin.
```

Al no encontrar solución coloqué una consulta en stackoverflow en inglés pero me la marcaron como duplicado, ya que supuestamente en este post está la solución: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815250/accessing-the-document-of-a-cross-domain-iframe-using-an-extension-in-chrome-45 el detalle es que esa solución funciona si uno tiene acceso al lado del cliente y al lado del servidor, cosa que yo no tengo.

Sé que es posible hacerlo porque hay extensiones como Multi-Highlight que permiten resaltar palabras de la página y acceden a la lista de trabajos sin problema. He tratado de ver el código de estas extensiones tratando de hacer ingeniería inversa, pero la verdad es que soy bastante nuevo programando y estoy un poco abrumado y perdido.

Desde ya agradecería cualquier pista o información al respecto.